# How to update node node with node.js?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I cannot update the node in the database with neo4j.the update process does not occur. If the problem is not the question of the code, I could not figure out the writing of the code.

```
app.post('/Movie/update',function(req, res){
    var title = req.body.title;
    var title = req.body.title2;
    session
        .run('MATCH (n:Movie {title:{titleParam}}) SET n.title={titleParam} RETURN n',{titleParam:title, title2Param:title})
        .then(function(result){
            res.redirect('/');
            session.close();
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

HTML code:

```
<form method="POST" action="/movie/update">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="text" name="title2">

    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @jfriesenhahn's answer, your Javascript code is also assigning 2 different values to the same `title` variable. You should use 2 different variables:

```
var title = req.body.title;
var title2 = req.body.title2;
session
    .run('MATCH (n:Movie {title: $title}}) SET n.title= $title2 RETURN n',
         {title: title, title2: title2})
```

or, more simply:

```
session
    .run('MATCH (n:Movie {title: $title}}) SET n.title= $title2 RETURN n',
         {title: req.body.title, title2: req.body.title2})
```

This answer also uses the now-preferred `$foo` syntax for parameters (instead of the deprecated `{foo}` syntax).

Answer (score 0):

So, it may just be a typo on your part, but you are using `titleParam` twice.
I think they cypher you are looking for is:

```
MATCH (n:Movie {title:{titleParam}}) SET n.title={title2Param} RETURN n
```